# Uninstalling GnuPG on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, gnupg

I recently tried installing GnuPG on MacOS High Sierra v10.13.3

After getting frustrated, I attempted to uninstall GnuPG by moving all folders I had downloaded associated with it to the Trash.

However, when I'm in terminal and I type in

```
    gpg
```

I get the response:

```
    gpg: WARNING: no command supplied. Trying to guess what you mean...
    gpg: Go ahead and type your message ...
```

At which point I have to use ctrl+z to stop the process, and which leads me to believe that GnuPG has not been fully uninstalled off my system.

Is there something I'm missing for uninstalling GnuPG? I'm wondering why I no longer receive a response like this:

```
    -bash: gpg: command not found
```

Thanks

Comment: Try running `type gpg` to see what you are actually invoking.

Comment: After running `type gpg` I get `gpg is hashed (/usr/local/bin/gpg)`

Comment: I believe this question would be better off on https://apple.stackexchange.com/ because it is not related to programming.

Comment: That looks like **homebrew** maybe. Did you install it with **homebrew**? If so, you can do `brew rm gpg --force`. Else, you can remove it with `rm /usr/local/bin/gpg`

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

Download the .dmg from here https://gpgtools.org/ then mount it and then double click the "Uninstall" icon.

It will ask you for your password and then it should uninstall the app and the commandline tool.

Answer (score 6):

If you installed gpgosx tools from sourceforge, try this:

```
sudo pkgutil --forget net.sourceforge.gpgosx 
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/gnupg-2.2
```